# C# ObservableCollection not adding items programmatically

Tags: c#, list, asynchronous, mvvm, observablecollection

I have a `method` returning a `List` to set a `ListView`'s `ItemSource`.
Here are the exact calls of the nested lists.

Here is the call of the `TabbedPage`

```
public ItemsMainTabbedPage(ObservableCollection<Titles> sortedItems)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        ItemsPagePro page = new ItemsPagePro(sortedItems, i);
        this.Children.Add(page);
    }                         
}
```

Here is the `ItemsPagePro` where is `ListView` is set

```
public ItemsPagePro(ObservableCollection<Titles> sortedItems, int switcher)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    switch (switcher)
    {
        case 0:
            Title = "Home";
            listView.ItemsSource = getTabbedListResults(sortedItems, (int)TabLoadMode.All);//0
            break;
        case 1:
            Title = "Safe";
            listView.ItemsSource = getTabbedListResults(sortedItems, (int)TabLoadMode.Safe);//1
            break;
        case 2:
            Title = "Risky";
            listView.ItemsSource = getTabbedListResults(sortedItems, (int)TabLoadMode.Risky);//2
            break;
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<Titles> getTabbedListResults(ObservableCollection<Titles> sortedItems, int switcher)
{
    var itemsSource = sortedItems;
    ObservableCollection<Titles> sortedItemsMain = new ObservableCollection<Titles>();
    ObservableCollection<Item> items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    try
    {
        bool safe = false;
        if(switcher == 1)
        {
            safe = true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsSource.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < itemsSource[i].Count; j++)
            {
                if(itemsSource[i][j].multiPassedMatchesHTML != null)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemsSource[i][j].multiPassedMatchesHTML.HTMLToParse))
                    {
                        itemsSource[i][j].DetailedTips = SampleDataSource.getDetailedTips(itemsSource[i][j].multiPassedMatchesHTML.multiPassedMatches, safe);
                        if (itemsSource[i][j].DetailedTips != null)
                        {
                            if (itemsSource[i][j].DetailedTips.totalMatches > 3)
                            {
                                bool checkResults = checkBeforeResults(itemsSource[i][j]);
                                if (checkResults)
                                {
                                    itemsSource[i][j].Tip = SampleDataSource.getHighestResultFromMultiPassedMatches(itemsSource[i][j].DetailedTips);
                                    itemsSource[i][j] = switchItemTip(itemsSource[i][j]);
                                    //if (switcher != 0)
                                    //{
                                        items.Add(itemsSource[i][j]);
                                        Console.WriteLine("Item added!");
                                    //}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //if(items.ToList().Count > 0)
            //{
                sortedItemsMain.Add(new Titles(items.ToList()) { Intro = itemsSource[i].Intro,  imagePath = itemsSource[i].imagePath, Summary = " - " });
            //}
            //items.Clear();
        }
        if(switcher == 0)
        {
            return itemsSource;
        }
        else
        {
            return sortedItemsMain;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Error:", ex.Message, "OK");
        return null;
    }
}
```

It is driving me crazy. While `switcher` is being changed to 0, 1, 2, this part is not being executed `if (switcher != 0)`. I can see that `switcher` is changing from the return of the method to `sortedItemsMain`. However the `Items` are empty while added here `items.Add(itemsSource[i][j]);`. Even if I remove the check to force the items adding, list is still empty.

EDIT: As I am finding out, this line is messing it up. itemsSource[i][j].Tip = ... When i try changing it's value(string), without any error it messes up the rest

Comment: Your code doesn't compile `ObservableCollection<Titles>` doesn't have indexer access like `itemsSource[i][j]`

Comment: Titles has a ObservableCollection<Item> inside it.

Comment: As I am finding out, this line is messing it up. itemsSource[i][j].Tip = ...
When i try changing it's value(string), without any error it messes up the rest